# Passing custom data in [UIButton addTarget]

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I add custom data while specifying a target in a `UIButton`?

```
id data = getSomeData();
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:event:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I want the `buyButtonTapped` function to look like:

```
(void) buyButtonTapped: (UIButton *) button event: (id) event data: (id) data
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

not possible. the action that is triggered by an UIControl can have 3 different signatures.

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

None of them allows you to send custom data.

---

Depending on what you want to do you can access the data in different ways.

For example if the button is in a UITableView you could use something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGPoint buttonOriginInTableView = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonOriginInTableView];
    NSData *customData = [myDataSource customDataForIndexPath:indexPath];
    // do something
}
```

There is always a way to get the data without passing it to the button.

Comment: That works. Thanks! It is indeed a custom button in a UITableView.The data I wanted was the UITableView itself to find out which button was clicked.

Comment: It's always a tableview ^^

Comment: "THere is always a way..." are you sure?

Comment: yes I am. Feel free to challenge me. But I have to admit, sometimes it takes some ugly workarounds or adding more instance variables.

Comment: it didn't work for me - so I had to change the second line to this:   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)contentView;

Comment: What if you have multiple buttons in each cell? How do you separate them?

Comment: @Michael you could call a different IBAction for each button in the cell. So if you have an up button and a down button, for example, you could have a function upButtonPressed for when the up button is pressed, and a function downButtonPressed for when the down button is pressed.

Comment: also works for collection views, thanks really innovative solution

Comment: What's happens if button clicked in a row, which was replaced by another row due to dataset updates/tableView reloads ? I think this is a bad solution in a tables which is frequently receive  updates for a dataset

Answer (score 21):

You cannot send extra data to the action method. There are a number of ways to associate the data with the button, although none are particularly straightforward unless the data is a single NSInteger.

- You can use the `tag` property to hold a single NSInteger. This may be all you need, or you could use it to look up an object in an array or dictionary.
- You can subclass UIButton to add ivars/properties to store your needed data.
- You can use `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:button]` as a key for a dictionary.
- My personal favorite for one-offs, you can use [associative references] to associate the data object with the button.

Comment: subclassing UIButton definitely does the trick and should be one of the correct answers imho

Comment: tag ended up being all I needed and saved me some time :) Otherwise, I would have subclassed. This is the better answer IMO

Comment: Option 4 makes no sense: You have to have some kind of selector to pass on to objc_setAssociatedObject, which NSHipster solves using a category, so why use opt. 4 at all?

Answer (score -3):

You can't really do that. What you can do is put the data in a dictionary and use the button to get it later.

E.g.

```
myDataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:someData, button, nil];
```

Then later;

```
-(void) buttonPress:(id)sender
{
  data = [dataDict objectForKey:sender];
}
```

If your buttons are specified in InterfaceBuilder you can use the 'tag' property of a button to lookup the data, although you will need to convert it to an NSNumber for use with the dictionary.

Comment: Note that using the button itself as the dictionary key will copy the button object, at which point it will probably no longer compare equal to the original. And the `tag` property can be used with or without IB.

Comment: @Anomie: in fact, I don't even think buttons can be copied, because they do not conform to `NSCopying`