# How to pass argument in @selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, arguments, selector

How can I pass an argument in the `@selector` for my code below?

```
[thisIconBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeIconState) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)changeIconState:(UITableViewCell*)thisCell
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Theres a way you can call a selector with multiple arguments, and this question was already answered... you can read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the colon is part of the selector: `@selector(changeIconState:)`.

Second, actions are methods that take a particular set of parameters — you can't just use any method as an action. Usually, actions look like this:

```
- (void)myAction:(id)sender;
```

where sender is a pointer to the object that's sending the action. In your code, when thisIconButton is tapped, that button would be passed as the sender.

Comment: I have a button on every cell. How can I do this?

Comment: Depends on how you set things up. You can examine the button's superview to figure out which cell it's in. Or, you can have the button target the cell instead of the view controller. The cell's action could then call your `-changeIconState:` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cell to which the button belongs, get it using `button.superview.superview` but I don't think you can alter the arguments of target methods for control events.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reasons for trying to send data through a selector is when you use a custom button in a UITableViewCell.

Matthias Bauch provided an excellent code sample on how to get the indexPath by looking up the cell on the sender in a related post. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690329/654870.