# UITextField inputView - Can the selected view reference the textfield?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker

If I have a set up like so:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField* )textField {

    if (textField.tag == 603) { 

        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(showDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        textField.inputView = datePicker;

    }

}
```

in the setDate method, can I reference which textField the UIPickerDate is the inputView of? That sounds confusing but like something like this:

```
- (void) showDate: (UIDatePicker*) myDatePicker {

    NSDate* selected = [myDatePicker date];
    NSString* date = [selected description];
    myTextField = myDatePicker.view //I know this is not a property

}
```

kind of in the same sense that a UITapGestureRecognizer knows what view is calling it...

Explanation for Woz: I could but it would make the app less dynamic. This is a big form for  the installation of medical devices. To create the form I store all the element properties in a dictionary (label, type (text, checkbox, segmented control), form section, etc.) and then each dict in an array in the proper order. I programatically build everything while in the array loop. I guess I could subclass UITextField...but you got to admit it would be nice to know which textfield initiated the inputView

Comment: Couldn't you store a pointer to the selected text field as a variable in your view controller?

Comment: I replied in an edit to my post.

Comment: Hmm, I see your problem. It's too bad `addTarget` won't let you pass other information.

Comment: : D Dang, I was just googling that...

Comment: Yea, I found questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690283/passing-custom-data-in-uibutton-addtarget But I didn't see a smooth solution for your situation.

Comment: @PruitIgoe Just a hack, you can put the tag of textField to dataPicker. And from the handler you find a reference to the textField using the viewWithTag:myDatePicker.tag.

Comment: @Anupdas - I was using tag to differentiate the textfield data types - 603 is a date field, 602 numeric non currency, 601 string...I think I might just subclass it, but I didn't know about viewWithTag so that makes your response awesome and upvoted!

Comment: @PruitIgoe I have put the above the above recommendation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just subclassed UITextField and got it to work:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.textColor = [colorManager setColor:66.0 :66.0 :66.0];
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(setDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.inputView = datePicker;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setDate : (UIDatePicker*) myDatePicker {

    NSDateFormatter* myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSString* dateString = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:myDatePicker.date];
    self.text = dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UITextField that triggered the UIDatePicker would be the current firstResponder. You can use this info to identify the textfield that is associated with the currently active UIDatePicker.

Answer (score -1):

Add a tag to UIDatePicker and use the tag to find textField from view.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField* )textField {

    if (textField.tag == 603) { 

        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [datePicker setTag:textField.tag];
        [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(showDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        textField.inputView = datePicker;

    }

}

- (void) showDate: (UIDatePicker*) myDatePicker {

    NSDate* selected = [myDatePicker date];
    NSString* date = [selected description];

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:myDatePicker.tag];

}
```

Comment: Anupdas doesn't work for me because I have two textfields with a tag of 603.

Comment: @PruitIgoe Thats a let down. See if you can give your textField a unique tag.

Comment: I just subclassed UITextField and got it working. Thanks for the help though.